# Google translate key missing on node js ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, google-translate

I have a simple Node JS script and which works fine when run locally in terminal:

```
exports.google_translate    = function (translate_text, res) {
var Translate       = require('@google-cloud/translate');
var translate       = new Translate.Translate({projectId: 'my project'});

translate.translate(translate_text, 'fr').then(results => {
    var translation     = results[0];
    res.send(translation);
}).catch(err => {
    res.send('ERROR:', err);
});
}
```

However whenever I call this via Ajax, I get the following error:

```
Error: The request is missing a valid API key.
```

I already added this as a permanent environmental variable using this:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH to key downloaded]"
```

But still each time I call this script via Ajax, I get the same error. So my question is, how can I get the Node JS script to save the API key so that it works when called via Ajax?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing the path to the json file to the constructor? `Translate({ keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for whatever reason, the application cannot read the environmental variable correctly. Since nodejs stores all environmental variables in the `process.env` you could ensure that it is written by calling:

```
function google_translate(translate_text) {
    process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "[PATH to key downloaded]";

    return translate.translate(translate_text, 'fr')
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

or pass the key directly to the constructor with

```
const translate = new Translate.Translate({
    projectId: 'my-project',
    keyFilename: "[PATH to key downloaded]"
});
```

You can also ensure the key file is read on your end and just pass the config to the translate constructor

```
const translate = new Translate.Translate({
    credentials: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("[PATH to key downloaded]", "utf8"))
});
```

if it still does not help, maybe it's the issue with a key itself, and you could try generating a new one here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: I used your solution to get it to work but found `new Translate.Translate()` is not a constructor but `new Translate()` worked

Comment: it depends on how you import the function

Answer (score 0):

```
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;    
const translate = new Translate({
        credentials: {
        "type": "account",
        "project_id": "your_project",
        "private_key_id": "your_data",
        "private_key": "your_data",
        "client_email": "your_data",
        "client_id": "your_data",
        "auth_uri": "your_data",
        "token_uri": "your_data",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "your_data",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "your_data"
        }
      });
const text = 'This is testing!';
const target = 'de';

async function translateText() {
    // Translates the text into the target language. "text" can be a string for
    // translating a single piece of text, or an array of strings for translating
    // multiple texts.
    let [translations] = await translate.translate(text, target);
    translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];
    console.log('Translations:' + translations);
  }
  
translateText();
```

You must take this `credentials.json` file from your project on google cloud. They will provide you a file `.json`